# Error when running simple pyspark code with cloudera CDH5.13

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera-cdh

I am running simple code as below. Actually I am just starting to practice spark with cloudera cdh. My goal is to read 'orders' table and then print it as RDD

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
if __name__ == "__main__":
 # create Spark context with Spark configuration
 conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Count")
 sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
 data = sc.textFile("hdfs://user/cloudera/orders")
 print data.collect()
```

But I am getting below Error

> [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ spark-submit spark_ex.py Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File "/home/cloudera/spark_ex.py", line 7, in
>   
>       print data.collect()   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 771, in
>   collect   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 813, in **call**   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line
>   308, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
>   java.net.ConnectException: Call From quickstart.cloudera/10.0.2.15 to
>   user:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused; For more details see: 
>   http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1508)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1441)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:786)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:260)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:2131)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1265)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$20.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1261)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1261)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:64)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.doGlob(Globber.java:272)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:151)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1734)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1959)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:405)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:648)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:744)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3000(Client.java:396)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1557)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1480)   ... 52 more

Can anyone please Thanks

Comment: Your URl is wrong. `hdfs://user` means you're trying to contact a server named "user". Get rid of one slash.

Comment: "/user/cloudera/orders" is enough, and you should use data.show() instead

Comment: Thanks :) let me try

Comment: Yes it worked !.. Thanks alot friends !